# set the limit in sql join statment which is under view

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am getting multiple rows of single property in this because I have left join the `property_image` table and it contains multiple images of same property.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Basic
AS
SELECT 
    crawlproperty_images.image_name as property_image 
FROM crawl_properties
    LEFT JOIN crawlproperty_images 
    ON (crawl_properties.id=crawlproperty_images.crawl_property_id)
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

That returns you the first row in SQL-SERVER:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Basic
AS
SELECT TOP 1
crawlproperty_images.image_name as property_image FROM crawl_properties
LEFT JOIN crawlproperty_images ON (crawl_properties.id=crawlproperty_images.crawl_property_id)
```

That returns you the first row in MySQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Basic
AS
SELECT
crawlproperty_images.image_name as property_image FROM crawl_properties
LEFT JOIN crawlproperty_images ON (crawl_properties.id=crawlproperty_images.crawl_property_id)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `TOP 1` is not MYSQL Syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIMIT in mysql as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Basic
AS
SELECT crawlproperty_images.image_name AS property_image 
FROM crawl_properties
LEFT JOIN crawlproperty_images ON (crawl_properties.id=crawlproperty_images.crawl_property_id) 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put limit in joins. But you can use limit at the end of the query.

For ex. 
select * from table t1 left join table t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
limit 10